# Attribute Parser

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, c++11, parsing

This is a challenge question from [hackerrank.com](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/attribute-parser).

> We have defined our own markup language HRML. In HRML, each element
>   consists of a starting and ending tag, and there are attributes
>   associated with each tag. Only starting tags can have attributes. We
>   can call an attribute by referencing the tag, followed by a tilde,
>   '`~`' and the name of the attribute. The tags may also be nested.
>
> The opening tags follow the format:
>
> ```
> <tag-name attribute1-name = "value1" attribute2-name = "value2" ... >
> ```
>
> The closing tags follow the format:
>
> ```
> < /tag-name >
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> <tag1 value = "HelloWorld">
> <tag2 name = "Name1">
> </tag2>
> </tag1>
> ```
>
> The attributes are referenced as:
>
> ```
> tag1~value  
> tag1.tag2~name
> ```
>
> You are given the source code in HRML format consisting of *N* lines.
>   You have to answer *Q* queries. Each query asks you to print the value
>   of the attribute specified. Print "Not Found!" if there isn't any such
>   attribute.
>
> #### Input Format
>
> The first line consists of two space separated integers, *N* and *Q*.
>   *N* specifies the number of lines in the HRML source program. *Q* specifies the number of queries.
>
> The following *N* lines consist of either an opening tag with zero or
>   more attributes or a closing tag.
>
> *Q* queries follow. Each query consists of string that references an attribute in the source program.
>
> #### Constraints
>
> 1 ≤ *N* ≤ 20
>   1 ≤ *Q* ≤ 20
>
> Each line in the source program contains, at max, 200 characters.
>
> Every reference to the attributes in the *Q* queries contains at max
>   200 characters.
>
> All tag names are unique.
>
> #### Output Format
>
> Print the value of the attribute for each query. Print "Not Found!"
>   without quotes if there is no such attribute in the source program.
>
> #### Sample Input
>
> ```
> 4 3
> <tag1 value = "HelloWorld">
> <tag2 name = "Name1">
> </tag2>
> </tag1>
> tag1.tag2~name
> tag1~name
> tag1~value
> ```
>
> #### Sample Output
>
> ```
> Name1
> Not Found!
> HelloWorld
> ```

Please review my code and let me know your suggestions.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>



int main() {
    std::string first;
    std::getline(std::cin, first);
    std::istringstream iss(first);
    std::vector<int> tokens1;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int> (iss),
                 std::istream_iterator<int>(),
                 std::back_inserter(tokens1));

    int n = tokens1[0], q=tokens1[1];
    std::string source;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> tagValue; 
    std::string tagKey;

    while( n > 0)
    {  
        std::string input;
        std::getline(std::cin, input);

        std::istringstream iss(input);
        std::vector<std::string> tokens;
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string> (iss), 
                   std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
                   std::back_inserter(tokens));

        if( tokens.size() >=1)
        {
            std::string tag = tokens[0];
            if( tag[0] == '<' && tag[1] != '/')
            {

                if( tag[tag.size()-1]== '>')
                     tagKey.empty() ? tagKey = tag.substr(1,tag.size()-2):
                                      tagKey = tagKey+"."+tag.substr(1, tag.size()-2);
                else
                     tagKey.empty() ? tagKey = tag.substr(1):
                                      tagKey = tagKey+"."+tag.substr(1);  
            }
            if( tag[0] == '<' && tag[1] == '/')
            {
                auto found = tagKey.find_last_of(".");
                if( found != std::string::npos)
                   tagKey.erase(tagKey.begin()+found, tagKey.end());
                else
                   tagKey="";
            }            
        }
        if(tokens.size() > 1 )
        {  
            int i = 1;
            while( i+2 < tokens.size() )
            {        
                std::string name = tokens[i];
                std::string value = tokens[i+2];
                if( value[value.size()-1]== '>')
                    tagValue[tagKey+"~"+name] = value.substr(1, value.length()-3);
                else
                    tagValue[tagKey+"~"+name] = value.substr(1, value.length()-2);
                i+=3;
            }
        }
        --n;

    }

    std::string input1;
    while(  std::getline(std::cin, input1)) 
    {

        if( q < 0)
            break;
         std::istringstream iss(input1);
         std::vector<std::string> tokens;
         std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string> (iss), 
                   std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
                   std::back_inserter(tokens));

         (tagValue.find(tokens[0]) != tagValue.end()) ? 
                                      std::cout<<tagValue[tokens[0]]<<"\n" :
                                      std::cout<<"Not Found!\n";
       --q; 
    }
}
```

Comment: So a question that reinvents XPath.

Comment: It looks like you could easily write a SGML Declaration for that (or perhaps even use the Reference Concrete Syntax), then use one of the standard libraries...

Answer (score 5):

Here are some ideas that may help you improve your code.

### Use functions

Right now this code is all one big block of code in `main`.  This makes it more difficult to read and understand than if functions were used.

### Simplify your code

Consider this sequence of code to read two integers:

```
std::string first;
std::getline(std::cin, first);
std::istringstream iss(first);
std::vector<int> tokens1;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int> (iss),
             std::istream_iterator<int>(),
             std::back_inserter(tokens1));

int n = tokens1[0], q=tokens1[1];
```

Now consider this version:

```
int n, q;
std::cin >> n >> q;
```

Which is easier to read and understand?  It's true they don't do the exact same thing, but I suspect the differences don't much matter in this case.

### Eliminate unused variables

Unused variables are a sign of poor quality code, and you don't want to write poor quality code. In this code, `source` is unused.  Your compiler may be smart enough to tell you about this if you ask it nicely.

### Don't `#include` headers that aren't needed

This code includes `<cmath>` and `<cstdio>` but neither are actually used.  Those lines should be deleted.

### Use appropriate data structures

The `tagKey` variable is a `std::string` and keeps the current tag stack as a `'.'` separated string.  However this gets messy and complex because "popping" a tag from the end means looking for that delimiter and then erasing just that bit.  I'd be inclined to create a class for that to encapsulate this complexity.  Here's one way to do that:

```
class StringStack : public std::deque<std::string> {
public:
    std::string asString() const {
        auto it{cbegin()};
        std::string str{*it};
        for (++it; it != cend(); ++it) {
            str += "." + *it;
        }
        return str;
    }
};
```

### Use a state machine

The logic of this code could be expressed as a state machine.  If that were done, one could process the stream "on the fly" character at a time with little difficulty.

### Prefer `unordered_map` to `map`

There's not really any reason that this code needs a `map` instead of an `unordered_map` and one generally gets a performance increase using the unordered version.

### An example

Using the suggestions above, my rewritten version of `main` looks like this:

```
int main() {
    constexpr std::size_t maxlinelen{200};

    int n, q;
    std::cin >> n >> q;
    std::cin.ignore(maxlinelen, '\n');

    auto tagValue{fetchTags(std::cin, n)};

    for(std::string query; q > 0 && std::getline(std::cin, query); --q) {
        auto search = tagValue.find(query);
        if (search == tagValue.end()) {
            std::cout << "Not Found!\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << search->second << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

I implemented a `fetchTags()` routine using a state machine and returning a `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>` but rather than spoil the fun, I'll leave it to you to implement your own.

Answer (score -2):

To get sample output I added `vector<string> results` at the beginning.

Then I changed your `while` loop to this:

```
 while(q!=0)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, input1);
         std::istringstream iss(input1);
         std::vector<std::string> tokens;
         std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string> (iss),
                   std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
                   std::back_inserter(tokens));

         (tagValue.find(tokens[0]) != tagValue.end()) ?
                                      results.push_back(tagValue[tokens[0]]+"\n") :
                                      results.push_back("Not Found!\n");
       --q;
    }
```

Finally, added a `for` loop for output:

```
for(auto &a: results){
        cout << a;
    }
```

Comment: Please explain why you think your modified `while` loop is an improvement over the one given in the question.